# NLTK download returns a parse error regarding xml

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I have python3 on my windows which i installed using anaconda. I am trying to run this piece of code downloading punkt from nltk but it returns the following error (image).

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
sent_segmenter = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle")

sentences = sent_segmenter.tokenize(st)
print(sentences)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-2eb0f40de2a3>", line 2, in <module>
    nltk.download('punkt')

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 787, in download
    for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force):

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 636, in incr_download
    info = self._info_or_id(info_or_id)

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 609, in _info_or_id
    return self.info(info_or_id)

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1019, in info
    self._update_index()

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 962, in _update_index
    ElementTree.parse(urlopen(self._url)).getroot()

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

  File "C:\Users\G751\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Comment: Copy and paste the error. Image won't help

Comment: @SreeramTP done.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
nltk.download(force=True)
```

This should work.